# openpyxl положение скрола

Tags: python, openpyxl

Файл excel сохраняет на определенной строке. То есть когда я открываю книгу мне приходится скролить её наверх, сохранять и уже потом отправлять клиенту. Как сохранить положение скрола?

Comment: Похожая проблема https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335452/python-openpyxl-set-cursor-on-the-chosen-cell

Comment: @AndyPavlov спасибо, за ссылку. Это она помогла мне понять в какую сторону рыть, как гуглить. К сожалению пока не один из методов не решил мою проблему.

Comment: Пример выложите простой — посмотрим, что с ним можно сделать.